# MySQL: Denormalization on many tables performance

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I need to decide which is better for performance:

A) Retrieving data from one of ~100 similar tables `LEFT JOIN` 1 table.

B) Retrieving data from one of ~100 similar tables after denormalizing 1 table that I joined in A).

I'm curious if denormalizing this one table pays off in `SELECT` performance, since I'm creating a lot more columns in database - similar tables will have 3-15(let's say 8) columns and the table to denormalize will have ~6columns.

So in variant A) I got **100** tables * **8** columns + **1** table * **6** columns = **806** columns.

In variant B) I got **100** tables * (**8** columns + **6** columns) = **1400** columns.

So which is better when we're not looking at disk space, only focusing on performance?

-------------EDIT-----------------

As Rick James asked for `SHOW CREATE TABLE` - the competing one :

```
CREATE TABLE `ItemsGeneral` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `datePosted` datetime NOT NULL,
 `dateEnds` datetime NOT NULL,
 `photos` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `locationSimple` point NOT NULL,
 `locationPrecise` point NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 SPATIAL KEY `locationPrecise` (`locationPrecise`),
 SPATIAL KEY `locationSimple` (`locationSimple`),
 KEY `userId` (`userId`),
 KEY `dateEnds` (`dateEnds`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And all the other ~100s tables will have tiny/small/medium ints.

Comment: How similar are these 100 tables? _"~100 similar tables"_ smells like a bad database design to begin with.

Comment: let's just ignore all the bad practices, I'm interested only in performance.

Comment: Performance is related to hardware and wise design to ease up the I/O. The way you visualize the tables isn't the way it's stored on disk or accessed on disk. Therefore, design the data model _properly_ before hunting for performance. You can also measure with two approaches and conclude which one yields better results. I agree with @Uueerdo - smells badly from the get go.

Comment: Sorry, I need to see code.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the competing `SELECTs`.

Comment: @RickJames Updated question

Comment: If it ain't normalised, it ain't an RDBMS, so I don't get where we're supposed to come in. You might as well use a ball of string and some chewing gum.

Comment: And the other table and the two selects?

Answer (score 0):

The implication of your question is that you already threw normalization out the window from the start.

In terms of performance, a standard rule of thumb in terms of result speed (I'll use > to mean faster than here)

*cached data > data cached query > query on SSD > query on magneto optical disk*

Another rule of thumb for database performance is that *optimization of the size of the data set is directly related to performance against a given resource.*

Now in terms of joins, there is a price to pay for a simple keyed join, but since these types of queries are typically measured in milliseconds, that certainly isn't a reason to denormalize lots of data and in the process blow up your dataset 20%, especially if you might need to update all that data.

Normalization is simply a cost for having atomic accurate data but it also helps keep your dataset to an optimal size.

Just as an example, if you have a mysql server, and you are using InnoDB, AND you have properly allocated memory on the server to your InnoDB cache, you can often see an extremely high cache hit ratio, where the queries are coming straight out of ram.  At that point the fact that more of your database can be in cache due to the size of the dataset is more important than the fact that you joined 2 tables together.

I find on the regular, that people who setup mysql but aren't experts in it, aren't aware either that the size of their dataset could fit entirely in cache (were they to allocate it), or that they haven't even changed any of the default values and have essentially almost no allocation to cache.

Just to be clear, this involves configuration of the innodb_buffer_pool_size and innodb_buffer_pool_instances.